# How to implement MVVM Custom Control?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, custom-controls

I have the Expense screen that contains a textbox where I can put the price of an expense. As I have built lot of logic (validation etc.) for this textbox I would like to extract it to a separate control and reuse it on other screens. I'm trying to build it in the mvvm style. Here's what I have for now:

**ExpenseView**

```
<page>
    <Label Text={Binding Date} />
    <wpfControls:CurrencyTextBoxView ViewModel="{Binding PriceViewModel}" />
</page>
```

**ExpenseViewModel**

```
public class ExpenseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ExpenseModel Model { get; }

  public string Date
  {
     get { return Model.Date.ToString(); }
     set 
     { 
       Model.Date = DateTime.Parse(value); 
       RaisePropertyChanged();
     }
  }

  private CurrencyTextBoxViewModel _priceViewModel;
  public CurrencyTextBoxViewModel PriceViewModel
  {
     get { return _priceViewModel; }
     set { _priceViewModel = value; }
  }
}
```

**ExpenseModel**

```
public class ExpenseModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; } // This is the bit I don't know how to implement correctly
}
```

**CurrencyTextBoxView**

```
<control>
    <TextBox Content={Binding Price} />
</control>
```

**CurrencyTextBoxViewModel**

```
public class CurrencyTextBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private CurrencyModel Model { get; }

  public string Price
  {
     get { return Model.Price.ToString(); }
     set 
     { 
       Model.Price = decimal.Parse(value); 
       RaisePropertyChanged();
     }
  }
}
```

**CurrencyModel**

```
public class CurrencyModel
{
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

---

And now the problem is: I need to have the Price property in my ExpenseModel as well (as it's being saved in the db). I don't want to have the Date property in my CurrencyModel (as not always it makes sense).

Should I keep the CurrencyModel inside of my ExpenseModel? How would I update it efficiently when the text in the currency textbox would change?
Also the ExpenseModel is located in different project than the rest of my classes and I wouldn't like to make this project dependend on the project with the CurrencyModel.

Should I listen to PropertyChanged events from CurrencyTextBoxViewModel and update the ExpenseModel.Price whenever the CurrencyTextBoxViewModel.Price string changes? I like the way my view models act as parsers of models for views (the Date property example). Is there any way to implement the PriceViewModel so that its getter returns data straight from the ExpenseModel (so it acts as a parser)?

I know there are lot of ways to implement it but I'm looking for the most mvvm-consistent one. Also, I'm not sure if I have implemented the whole pattern correctly?

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Your custom control should be like any other control.  Tell me--is there a TextBoxViewModel?  What about a GridViewModel?  Does the RichTextBox come with a RichTextBoxViewModel?  **No.** Don't fall into the trap where you believe MVVM == no codebehind.  If you have UI logic that's associated with a custom control, place it in the codebehind.  Does your custom control need X, Y, and Z to do its job?  Add properties for X, Y and Z on the surface of your control.  Bind those to your ViewModels.  It's simple and works great.

Answer (score 0):

As for `Date` property, place it only on the view model if it needs no serialization.

How I would do:
If you want to reuse your `CurrencyTextBox`, I would not tie the control with the model. No `CurrencyModel` is needed. Prepare a `DependencyProperty` (say `CurrencyText`) on `CurrencyTextBox`. The view goes as:

```
<xxx:CurrencyTextBox CurrencyText="{Binding Currency}" />
```

You can omit `CurrencyTextBoxViewModel` because the `CurrencyText` can be bound to the internal `TextBox.Text` (or, just update relevant property on the view model). Anyway, with two-way binding, when `CurrencyText` is updated, `ExpenseViewModel.Currency` is also update, and here you can update your model.

I think it is ok to listen event of the model because the view model live shorter than the model. However you should block propagate event firing if the new value is the same as the old one.

The model serves as the origin of data and does business logic. The view model is just a shadow of the model, thus it is usually thin. Consider using some MVVM frameworks to get a sense of that.

Comment: I don't know why haven't I thought of having a dependency property other than ViewModel for my CurrencyTextBoxView.

Comment: Regarding having the model and the view model for my custom control - this is my hobby project. At work we don't really do mvvm in a good way. It always gets messy after some time. Therefore, even though I'm aware that having the model and the view model in this case just makes stuff more complicated I'd rather stick to it.

Soon I should have some more time to work on it so I'll post a comment of what I have managed to do.